# SQL Server 2012 installation on Windows 8.1 Single Language

Tags: windows-8, sql-server-2012

I tried to install SQL Server 2012 with SP1 on Windows 8.1 Single Language, but it terminates straight after starting with this helpful error:

[image]

I've read that you need SQL Server 2012 SP2 on Windows 8, but from what I can see in MSDN and Wikipedia there is no such thing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Outside of the fact your getting a blank error message, your question, the major confusion is what you have read exactly.  SQL Server 2012 isn't required to be installed, its entirely optional, most average people don't have a license for what your installing.  Its something they install development machines and Windows Server installations.

Comment: @Ramhound What I meant is, I've read that you can only install SQL 2012 (on Win8) if it has SP2. But there is no SP2. (I'm installing a licensed version off MSDN on a development machine.)

Comment: I wasn't even aware Service Pack 1 existed.  You do have MS SQL Server 2012 already installed right?  The language of this installation is the same as Windows, otherwise that will be a problem, since your version of Windows does not support language packs.

Comment: @Ramhound - brand new laptop (nothing pre-installed), same language; just a PEBCAK (problem exists between chair & keyboard). ;)

Answer (score 1):

Ignore me. I was clicking the setup.exe file in ISO viewer, without having mounted the ISO as a virtual drive first.